# JQuery Accordion style change when open

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am trying to get a jQuery accordion to change the corner-roundedness based on whether it is active and whether it is the top, bottom, or sandwiched between the top and bottom headers.

I want the box that the accordion is contained in to be rounded on the top and bottom no matter what. By default, the accordion theme also has rounded corners on headers that are closed.

Is there a style method that can dictate to the accordion that, when inactive and between the top and bottom, to have 90-degree angles, while the bottom will have rounded corners while inactive, and 90-deg corners when active? Or is this going to be a more complicated exercise, with customized javascript?

Comment: First, I assume you're referring to something like what they offer [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)? Second, can you provide more example, not quite getting what to round and not round, getting lost in explination

Comment: you should see jquery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ for this you will get help. Or else show your code so we can see what exactly you want.

Comment: Also, if you use jQueryUI's accordion you can use the `change` func in its options to adjust corners (aka add and remove corner classes) as needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the .addClass and .removeClass to change the css of the accordion headers div element based on certain events? Active would be dictated when it is clicked on? Deactive when it is click on again to hide it?

You can check the .parent() or .sibling() elements to determine if it is below/beside/underneath other accordion header div elements?

Comment: Right, I think this is the way to go. I'll implement and if it works well, I'll check as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a CSS-only solution, maybe something like this will do what you want:

```
.accordion {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.accordion [aria-expanded=false] {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.accordion [aria-expanded=true] {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.accordion > [aria-expanded=false] + :last-child {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.accordion > [aria-expanded=true] + :last-child {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

In place of `.accordion`, you should put whatever selector will match your accordion. Keep in mind that this will not work in IE8 and earlier but it should work in most other recent browsers. I haven't actually tried this so I am not completely sure if it will work at all.

Comment: I haven't seen the use of less-than or plus-sign symbols in CSS before. I'll have to read up on the new methods.